# Docker container can't connect to Mosquitto MQTT broker running in another container on the same network

Tags: docker, mqtt, mosquitto, docker-network

I've got two programs that are supposed to communicate via MQTT. One starts up a broker process and listens for messages from the other. When run locally, this all works, but inside Docker it doesn't. The Docker compose file has this for the ports of the mqtt container:

```
ports:
 - "1883:1883"
```

I have also tried this, which didn't make any difference:

```
expose:
- "1883"
```

So it should just be the default port exposed. Within that container, the mosquitto_pub command can hit that port for "localhost" without error, but if the IP address assigned to the container or the name of the container is used for that command instead of localhost, the result is "Connection refused". Other containers can't use localhost for such a command (at least in Docker, this part works when run directly on my local machine), but if they use the IP/container name they also get connection refused.

A completely invalid host name will result in a different failure message, so I know at least the name is correct. Additionally, the mosquitto broker produces the message "Error: Cannot assign requested address" when started on localhost (or 0.0.0.0) in a Docker container, but not outside, and still continues running otherwise seemingly without error.

EDIT: The mosquitto.conf file is the default, without modifications.

Comment: How are you running the client and server? If you are using `docker run` and not Docker Compose you will need to explicitly put them on the same Docker virtual network, otherwise they will be insulated from each other (normally this is a good thing).

Comment: Are the client and the server in containers, or is one of them on the host, and the other in a container?

Comment: (Note that "localhost" in a container is (by default) not the same address/network as "localhost" on the host machine).

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77418936/edit) the question to include the `mosquitto.conf` you have mounted into the continaer (the default will NOT allow external connections)

Comment: They are put together via compose. They are explicitly part of the same network within docker. The client & server are in separate Docker containers, none of them running directly on the local machine rather than through Docker.
Is the connection "external" if they are both put on the same network in Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default mosquitto config only listens on `localhost` so can not be connected from anything outside the container

You need to create a local file called `mosquitto.conf` with the following content:

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
```

and mount it on `/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf`

```
  volumes:
    - "./mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf"
```